# Nginx Sub Filter does not apply to images in static directory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

```
location ^~ /admin {
            alias /etc/nginx/admin;
            #sub_filter_types text/xml text/css text/javascript image/jpeg image/png image/gif image/webp image/svg+xml;
            sub_filter_types *;

            sub_filter 'static/js/' 'admin/static/js/';
            sub_filter 'href="/favicon' 'href="/admin/favicon';
            sub_filter 'static/css/' 'admin/static/css/';
            sub_filter 'static/media/' 'admin/static/media/';
            sub_filter 'href="manifest.json' 'href="admin/manifest.json';

            sub_filter_once off;
            try_files $uri $uri /admin/index.html;

    }
```

I am deploying multiple applications with one domain

When connected with the above settings, it works well and most of them work.

But only one problem, only the image files in /static/media the sub_filter is not applied.

My image is a png file, and when I hit the header

A response of image/png is checked.

so I
sub_filter_types text/xml text/css text/javascript image/jpeg image/png image/gif image/webp image/svg+xml;

has been used. But sub_filter was not applied.

What I found a workaround:
sub_filter_types *;

, and applying the sub_filter was successful.

What's the matter?

sub_filter_types *; does not want to be used because it has performance issues.